# How can I learn to write thrillers?

Tags: thriller

I'm newbie in writing books. How can I learn to write thrillers?

There are [books to learn how to write](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/148/what-are-good-reads-about-writing), and other resources. But how can I learn to specifically write thrillers? What skills do I need to learn, compared to writing in more general genres?

Are there any books to which I can refer for writing some thriller stories?

Comment: We already have a very similar question that may help you: [What are good reads about writing?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/148/what-are-good-reads-about-writing) I think that, if you're truly new to writing, you may want to read one of these before getting into the specific tropes and techniques of thrillers. ([Reading a lot in your chosen genre](http://writers.stackexchange.com/a/15/26) may well help you learn those.)

Comment: In order to avoid this being closed as a duplicate, have edited this into a question that asks what skills one will need in the genre of thrillers, as well as asking for resources. I hope this will help you, but please [revert my edit](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/editing) if I've missed the mark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is not necessary to read about writing thrillers to write them. Insted, I'd read thrillers directly, so you can see how they're written.

However, you can also check these links with some advices:

1. http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Thriller-Novel
2. http://www.creative-writing-now.com/how-to-write-a-thriller.html
3. http://davidmorrell.net/on-writing/writing-advice/

I hope it's useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Learning to write any genre of fiction is mostly the same set of skills - character exposition, scene setting, pacing, and so on.  Start with the general and then move on to the specifics would be my suggestion.

I don't follow the thriller genre much, but in my chosen genre (science fiction) there are a lot of popular authors who write blogs where they discuss writing topics.  Are you following your favourite authors' blogs?  It's also worth looking for publishing industry blogs (e.g. editors or agents) that might put a broader perspective on things.

And, as always, make sure you're reading a lot.  Be well-read both inside and outside your genre -- both are critical.